# Hints on solving $y'=\frac{y}{3x-y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y'=\frac{y}{3x-y^2}$$

**My attempt:**

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{3x-y^2}$$

$$dy\cdot(3x-y^2)=dx\cdot y$$

$$dy\cdot3x-dy\cdot y^2=dx\cdot y$$

Any direction?

I need hints please $\color{red}{not}$ a full answer

Comment: Usually folks write $y' = dy/dx$, not $y' = dx/dy$.  Are you *sure* you want $y' = dx/dy$?  Cheers!

Comment: yes, I know ,edited

Comment: what is the type of the equation?

Comment: You fixed the $\frac{dy}{dx}$, but the later lines still use $\frac{dx}{dy}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the hint given by Chinny84, we write the equation as $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = \frac{3x-y^2}{y} = \frac{3x}{y} -y$$

So $$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} - \frac{3x}{y} = -y$$ which is a linear first order differential equation in $x$.

Spoiler: Answer below.

> Using an integrating factor $$I = \exp\left({\int \frac{-3}{y}}\, \mathrm{d}y \right) = \frac{1}{y^3}.$$
>
> We get that $$\frac{x}{y^3}= \int \frac{1}{y^3}\cdot-y \, \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{y} + \mathrm{c}.$$
>
> Multiplying through by $y^3$ yields 
>
> $$x = \mathrm{c}y^3 + y^2$$

Comment: OP: "please not a full answer"

Comment: Spoilered, didn't notice that.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks

Comment: cool thing that you did with "Answer below"

Answer (score 2):

I would write it as
$$
\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \frac{3x-y^2}{y} = 3\frac{x}{y} -y
$$
Just maybe

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{3x-y^2}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{3x-y^2}{y}$$

$$\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{3x}{y}=-y$$, Which is linear in $x$